# How can I recover data from lost and found files present on root.disc from Windows?

Tags: grub2, kernel, data-recovery, dd

After changing size of Ubuntu folder (the command I used was `dd`, folder `loop0`) the kernel panicked, my Ubuntu is dead and I cannot recover it with GRUB or any recover tool (vmlinuz is not even present).

Is it possible to recover files from Ubuntu's partition while I am logged into a Windows system? I have some program to open Ubuntu's root.disc, but only "lost and found" files are listed there.

Comment: `dd` does not change the size of folder. It copies, or overwrites partitions. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1116120/edit) your question above and write down exactly the `dd` and other commands you used. It is possible you deleted everything in the hard drive or partition. Windows does not natively recognize Ubuntu partitions. Chances of recovering something from Windows is slim.

Comment: Close voters. Answered.

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't natively recognize the vast majority of Ubuntu file systems so the odds of data recovery from within Windows are virtually non-existent. You do have exceptionally good odds of recovering your data booted from Ubuntu live media and utilizing advanced data recovery tools such as `testdisk` As outlined in numerous posts here such as:

[Partitions disappeared after power loss while installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing)

[Recovering a lost file with testdisk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818890/recovering-a-lost-file-with-testdisk)