# Recovering deleted files with rm -rf

Tags: rm, df

I accidentally deleted a directory with

```
rm -rf /media/directory
```

When using

```
ls -lh /media
```

the space appears to be free, but when I use `df` or open the file manager `nautilus` or `pantheon`, it shows that the previously occupied space is still allocated.

I googled this problem and some says that some process is still using these data, so it won't be freed till unmount, restart or killing the process itself. I did none of these still, is there any way to recover it?

Comment: I did this too before, (sometimes must be the first one I guess?) Try a tool named foremost, to recover some files  as a shortcut here:  foremost -v -t <dir to recover or /device> I THINK I can be wrong, it was long ago I used foremost but I think that's it ; Hope it fixes itself! good luck - It's never fun to accid. delete stuff, trust me I've been there.

Comment: i opened the computer to solely backup the directory that i deleted with rm -rf

Comment: The best thing to do is stop using the computer now, logout and boot up with a live USB or DVD and recover the files using foremost or [testdisk / photorec](https://askubuntu.com/a/819070/167115) (photorec recovers more than just photos). Ideally, it would be best to also have a spare USB storage device to dump the files onto. Using testdisk or photorec, the files (or pieces of the files that are left) will no longer have the original file names but the actual data (deleted files) may be recovered from the available free space (Select a directory on the USB storage for the recovered files).

Comment: I usually use photorec (which is included in the testdisk package) to recover deleted files and I select all the filetypes but I believe testdisk is supposed to be capable of undeleting files or at least recovering deleted files from the free space of the specified partition. [See here for more information](https://askubuntu.com/a/819070/167115).

Comment: Please let us know if [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/819070/167115) does not answer your question and why (again, I suggest doing this from a live USB and using another USB or other storage device to recover the files to, you may need a lot of space as this may recover lots of previously deleted data. If you know the filetypes you are looking for, you can narrow the search down with photorec to limit the filetypes).

Comment: primarily text files and pdfs

Comment: Also, take a look at [these various answers to your question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files). Although again, I can't stress enough how important it is to run the recovery from a USB live session so you don't overwrite any of the deleted data.

Comment: i wanna keep my computer up , as i aforementioned some people say there is a process using it , and that's why both the file managers and df is still reading the previously occupied space .... i was wondering if there is a way to recover the data instead of typical recovery

Comment: @mostafa Okay, I see what you are saying; this is a good question.

Comment: @mostafa However if absolute recovery is most important, you might want to try one of those methods.

Comment: @mostafa [I think this is the answer you are looking for](https://www.linux.com/news/bring-back-deleted-files-lsof/) but I have never tried this myself. lsof was the first thing I thought of because it shows what files are in use which is how I found the answer.

Comment: If you use this lsof method, I think it would be safest to use to output the recovered files to a separate storage device if possible. [Here is another example](https://www.masterkenneth.com/2019/03/using-lsof-to-recover-deleted-files/).

Comment: when i accidentally delete the /media directory which contains another directory where i mount /dev/sda5 partition .... it indicated that it can't delete it's in process ... but  its files were already gone because of the f ... that's the exact scenario of what happened ... i was wondering if it has something to do with the mount point not the device file

Comment: i used lsof to detect one of the files ... that was the output 

`lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
`

Comment: @mostafa That doesn't look like the file. Try lsof | grep deleted

Comment: @mostafa If you don't see any of the actual filenames listed, then you will have to use a different method like photorec or testdisk. If you remember any of the filenames, you can search for the specific file by using `grep` with `lsof`. For example, to search for a file named "awesome.pdf" you could use `lsof | grep 'awesome.pdf'` or you could search for directory: `lsof | grep '/media/'` If the actual files don't list after you run the command, then you will have to use `foremost` or `photorec`, preferably from a live USB session.

Comment: i tried this method of recovering the files with lsof and /proc ... turned out to be that it only works if the files is being opened by some program like for instance nano or less is processing on the file .... and you opened another window and removed it then this method will definitely work ... but i had none of the deleted files opened by another process yet they somehow still exist

Comment: @karek i did try testdisk out , but it only recovered the file names , like for instance i had multiple text files it recovered the file itself being empty

Comment: photorec did retrieve only some text files in a splitted separates files  , had to use cat and export them somewhere .... and used testdisk to get the only the name of the deleted files / directories